# Function performed by a shortcut in Pages?

Tags: pages, shortcut

I'm writing a lot of text with Pages. Upon typing I'm not always staring at my keyboard and from time to time when using the space bar I inadvertantly type command functions.
Most of the time I can easily recover this typing errors by looking at the dynamical 1st entry of the `Edit` menu which suggest to undo the wrong command (shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>). But this isn't always possible.

Now I just inadvertantly typed <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

I don't see an immediate and total collapse of my actual page.

But I would like to know if this modified my document somewhere else
before saving a damaged document.

How may I find what this shortcut is doing?
How may I find what any shortcut is doing?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not a canonical list of shortcut keys provided by the program in an easy to find way, however, some third party software has cataloged most Apple apps and some others too.

Give [Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) a try, I think this will answer your question with this program, as well as a great many others.

In short, after installing it, you hold down command, and it gives you a list of shortcuts relevant to the active app.